# Random Forest - variables in the training data missing in newdata

Tags: r, random-forest

I tried to see if there is any imbalance in the predictors between train/test datasets. Originally the exposure was 'integer' and I converted to number for both datasets.

```
as.numeric(test$Age_MIR)
as.numeric(train$Age_MIR)

train<- sani %>% 
  select (LVEDV, LVESV, LVSV, LVEF, LVEDM, RVEDV, RVESV, RVSV, RVEF, Age_MIR, RAEDVsimp, RAESVsimp, 
          RARes, RAPump, LAEDVsimp, LAESVsimp, LARes, LAPump, AoED, AoES, AHA_1, AHA_2, AHA_3, AHA_4,
          AHA_5, AHA_6, AHA_7, AHA_8, AHA_9, AHA_10, AHA_11, AHA_12, AHA_13, AHA_14, AHA_15,
          AHA_16,Global, PWV) %>%
  filter (LVEDV>0, LVESV>0, LVSV>0, LVEF>0, LVEDM>0, RVEDV>0, RVESV>0, RVSV>0, RVEF>0, Age_MIR>0, RAEDVsimp>0, RAESVsimp>0, 
          RARes>0, RAPump>0, LAEDVsimp>0, LAESVsimp>0, LARes>0, LAPump>0, AoED>0, AoES>0, AHA_1>0, AHA_2>0, AHA_3>0, AHA_4>0,
          AHA_5>0, AHA_6>0, AHA_7>0, AHA_8>0, AHA_9>0, AHA_10>0, AHA_11>0, AHA_12>0, AHA_13>0, AHA_14>0, AHA_15>0,
          AHA_16>0, Global>0, PWV>0)

test <- malati %>% 
  select (LVEDV, LVESV, LVSV, LVEF, LVEDM, RVEDV, RVESV, RVSV, RVEF, Age_MIR, RAEDVsimp, RAESVsimp, 
          RARes, RAPump, LAEDVsimp, LAESVsimp, LARes, LAPump, AoED, AoES, AHA_1, AHA_2, AHA_3, AHA_4,
          AHA_5, AHA_6, AHA_7, AHA_8, AHA_9, AHA_10, AHA_11, AHA_12, AHA_13, AHA_14, AHA_15,
          AHA_16, Global, PWV) %>%
  filter (LVEDV>0, LVESV>0, LVSV>0, LVEF>0, LVEDM>0, RVEDV>0, RVESV>0, RVSV>0, RVEF>0, Age_MIR>0, RAEDVsimp>0, RAESVsimp>0, 
          RARes>0, RAPump>0, LAEDVsimp>0, LAESVsimp>0, LARes>0, LAPump>0, AoED>0, AoES>0, AHA_1>0, AHA_2>0, AHA_3>0, AHA_4>0,
          AHA_5>0, AHA_6>0, AHA_7>0, AHA_8>0, AHA_9>0, AHA_10>0, AHA_11>0, AHA_12>0, AHA_13>0, AHA_14>0, AHA_15>0,
          AHA_16>0, Global>0, PWV>0) 



# Develop the model in the train set
rf.model <- randomForest (Age_MIR ~ LVEDV + LVESV+ LVSV + LVEF+ LVEDM + RVEDV + RVESV + RVSV + RVEF + Age_MIR + RAEDVsimp + RAESVsimp+ 
          RARes + RAPump + LAEDVsimp + LAESVsimp + LARes + LAPump +  AoED + AoES + AHA_1 + AHA_2 + AHA_3 + AHA_4 +
          AHA_5 + AHA_6 + AHA_7 + AHA_8 + AHA_9 + AHA_10 + AHA_11 + AHA_12 + AHA_13 + AHA_14 + AHA_15 +
          AHA_16 + Global + PWV, data = train, importance = TRUE) 

importance (rf.model)

# predict model performance in the test set

rf.predict<- predict (rf.model, test)
```

```
Error: Error in predict.randomForest(rf.model, test) : 
  variables in the training data missing in newdata
```